# What is the benefit of copy over xcopy on the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer, robocopy, xcopy

I know that xcopy has more options however are there any benefits to using copy rather than xcopy?

Comment: _Which_ copy? [This one](http://jpsoft.com./help/copy.htm)? [This one](http://microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/copy.mspx)?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

1. *xcopy* is an external program, while *copy* is part of the interpreter (*cmd.exe*, *command.com*). This means that *xcopy* might not be present on another machine or a rescue disk.

   Since we have Windows and rescue CDs, that isn't really an issue anymore.
2. *copy* can concatenate files.

   ```
   copy file1 + file2 file3
   ```

   creates a file (*file3*) which contains *file1*'s and *file2*'s contents.
3. *copy* can copy more than just files.

   For example,

   ```
   copy con file
   ```

   lets you write directly from the keyboard (console) to *file*.

   Likewise, you can print a file using

   ```
   copy file prn
   copy file \\computer\printer
   ```

   where the latter is for shared printers.

   You can even combine the above: The command

   ```
   copy con prn
   ```

   lets you write directly to the printer.

Comment: Also, it's one less character to type when invoking it. :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for info regarding files concatenation. I've just found out it and understood why my result file was so big. You've made my day.

Answer (score 28):

I think the main difference is (or was) that `xcopy` is able to copy folder hierarchies and `copy` was intended to work on files only.
That being said, I don't think there is anything to gain (functionality- or performance-wise) from using `copy`.

Please note, even `xcopy` is outdated by today's standards. [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) is the new copy utility of choice on modern Windows platforms.

Also note that all the mentioned copy utilities have Wikipedia articles that could contain further information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_(command)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcopy
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Answer (score 1):

Anyone remember DOS on dual floppy PCs? Xcopy minimises the number of read seeks by loading multiple files into memory on a single read to speed up the copy. Probably still makes a trivial speed improvement with HDDs.

Comment: At the risk of splitting hairs, this is not, strictly speaking, an answer to the question, since it asks for benefit(s) of `copy` over ``xcopy``.  But, IMO, this is a valid contribution to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider Powershell a "command line" then there is another "copy" command available.  The Powershell "copy" apparently maps to a cmdlet.

One thing not mentioned by the other answers is that since Powershell expands a deeply embedded wildcard at the shell level, this command will work (only from PS not from DOS):

```
% copy G:\git\one\source\*\morePath\SomePattern*.dll destDir
```

while xcopy claims "file not found" since it accepts a single source.

Answer (score 0):

One command line argument to pay attention to between copy and xcopy is /V.

While xcopy's help states /V has xcopy compare source and destination file sizes, copy does not state the method used to verify the copy was accurate.

I suspect, but do not know, if the internal command, copy, being primarily a file command verse a directory command, uses CRC or binary compare to verify the copied file.